# A challenging question in (projective?) geometry about lines defined by a quadrilateral

Tags: euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, projective-geometry

I have recently found this interesting question:

> **Q:** Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with sides having different
>   lengths.
>  Two distinct points $P,Q$ are said a *happy couple* if
>   $\widehat{APB}=\widehat{AQB}=\widehat{CPD}=\widehat{CQD}$.
>  Prove
>   that all the lines defined by a happy couple share a common point.

[image]

I have managed to find a proof through powers and cross-ratios, but I am not entirely satisfied by it and I feel that a more elementary solution eluded me, which is the reason for posing this question. Some considerations:

1. A happy couple defines / is defined by a couple of circles with chords $AB,CD$ which are mapped into each other by a spiral similarity;
2. The line defined by a happy couple is precisely the radical axis of the previous circles and the radical axis of $\Gamma_{AB},\Gamma_{CD}$ is the locus of points $R$ such that $\text{Pow}(R,\Gamma_{AB})=\text{Pow}(R,\Gamma_{CD})$.

Comment: The only thing I am somewhat unable to get to grips with is the sides being unequal. Is it that two sides being equal does not guarantee the existence of a happy couple? Or is it because the result does not hold in such a case?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: it is just a constraint for avoiding parallel lines (instead of concurring lines).

Comment: What does $\widehat{APB}$ mean? It cannot be guessed from the figure.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: the amplitude of the angle formed by $A,P,B$ with vertex at $P$, as usual.

Comment: Don't we have $\angle(APB)$ for this?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: just a synonym, according to the notation I am used to.

Comment: I'm curious: what tool did you use to draw the picture?